# simplest jQuery font resizer

Tags: jquery

What is the simplest way of increasing / decreasing font sizes on click of trigger element?

I've seen a few scripts and plugins etc, but they all look fairly verbose.
What's the simplest way to neatly achieve this?

Comment: Include links to plugins you think are to verbose ...

Answer (score 3):

use the following syntax

```
 $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
```

[font resize](http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/text-resizing-with-jquery/)